# Python execute xquery to marklogic

Tags: python, sql, python-3.x, marklogic

It's not allowed to modify the data inside `MarkLogic`, so the problem is I can't execute `SQL query`. Only `XQY` allowed because the data is not like a table.

How to execute the xquery under python3 pass to Django Rest Framework? The only problem is I can't execute sql in marklogic because `name` are in array format. only xquery can do the task
There is a way to execute xquery directly in marklogic? or do i need to bind like `zorba`?

here's my code look like, .

```
def search(request):
        search = request.GET.get("user_input", 'default')
        if request.method == 'GET':
            service = xSQL()
            rs = service.post(
                {}, 
                "select Id from Table where name contains '%" + search + "%'"
                )
            return Response(rs)
```

json load in marklogic:

```
{
    "envelope": {
        "instance": {
            "Form": [
                {
                    "Id": "202102151",
                    "year": "2021",
                    "group":"test",
                    "name": [
                        "Jame","Mark","Hero","Vince"
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that your goal is to load JSON documents and then query for rows via SQL (which is a common goal), you'll need to define a view in MarkLogic so that you can run a SQL query against that view. TDE is a fairly easy way to define a view with whatever columns you want based on path expressions - https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/app-dev/TDE . You can use qconsole to define and insert a TDE into your schemas database and then verify that your SQL statement will work.

Once you have that in place, you can use the /v1/eval endpoint - https://docs.marklogic.com/REST/POST/v1/eval - to submit a statement using https://docs.marklogic.com/xdmp.sql (or xdmp:sql, which is the XQuery equivalent, but JavaScript is usually easier).

Comment: Small note  - in addition to the eval endpoint, the v1/rows endpoint has an accept type of : application/sql for which you can then post the SQL there and return content.  And of course, if you ave a view, you could also us a MarkLogic ODBC server as well, I would imagine

Comment: That's a great point - I forgot that /v1/rows supports direct SQL queries. That's likely the easiest way to go.